# Why does katoolin break my Ubuntu 16.04 instalation?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, graphics, katoolin

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, after breaking it for the fifth time and reinstalling it for the sixth. I tried to install select Kali tools using Katoolin using these instructions: http://www.tecmint.com/install-kali-linux-tools-using-katoolin-on-ubuntu-debian/
When I was done installing, I would reboot and then start classicmenu indicator to set it up and get rid of any duplicate menu items, etc. Then I would use my laptop as normal (Acer Chromebook CB3-111-C8UB). After the second boot up at another time, the login screen would appear as normal and then when I log in, nothing happens. The log in screen just disappears. not even the wallpaper has changed though, so the password prompt and pretty much anything that was interactive on screen just faded away. I did hours of research and all of these symptoms led me to believe that this is a screen driver issue. I followed numerous guides to installing the correct drivers or whatever i need to install and clean and reinstall, even reinstalling unity and trying to install xfce. I have access to tty and all other things are working as far as I know (wifi and keyboard at least), but when I log into tty it gives Kali/GNU or whatever disclaimer. The reason I do not want to simply install Kali is because the desktop environment is no where close to as smooth unity is on this laptop. I have tried running Katoolin with and without disk/home encryption (I normally encrypt disk and home folder, so I thought this was the problem). I have even found the same question, but when I actually go to the site, it has been removed by the author. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't ask us. Ask the maintainer of Katoolin. And before we can give an answer you will need to find an error message or find something in a log for us to answer on. All this is now is a statement; not a question or problem to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen multiple people reporting odd and serious problems after installing katoolin or "Kali tools" in Ubuntu. Problems such as boot/login issues, or even Ubuntu now identifying itself in the terminal as *being* Kali Linux. In general it's a bad idea to "mix and match" operating system components unless you know exactly what you're doing.

I would recommend a fresh install of Ubuntu, and then either

- installing the individual pentesting tools you need separately on your own in Ubuntu (but not through adding entire Kali repositories to your system)
- installing Kali on a separate partition -- it's designed for professional penetration testing, not to be a super-"smooth" desktop. If you're using it for what it's intended for, the "smooth"ness of the desktop won't matter as much as the functionality of the powerful tools that you (presumably) need for your job or research.